# Merge field {{{Recipient.name}}} not working for User as Recipient in Lightning email template

Tags: lightning, email-template, email-alert

I'm trying to create a Lightning email template on Lead Object. It is giving below error:
[image]

This works fine if the recipient is a contact record but fails if a user is selected.

And same thing works with user record if I use `{!Recipient.name}` instead of `{{{Recipient.name}}}`.

But I can't have this - `{!Recipient.name}` syntax in lightning email template as it gives error while saving.

Comment: Your question is slightly confusing, let me try to clarify. You are seeing different behaviours using HML for Lead, Contacts and Users, correct? If so, this is expected as per [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.handlebars_template_language.htm&type=5). If I read your question incorrectly, you may wish to elaborate on the problem you are facing in isolation.

Comment: You're totally right! So, if the recipient is going to be a any record owner(User). We should use classic email template only right? Or is there a work around to keep using lightning email template for user as recipient?

Comment: To continue using Lightning Email Template for User, use SML (Salesforce Markup Language) like `{!Recipient.name}`. Unfortunately you cannot use SML and HML dynamically in a single email template which means you should have a separate Lightning Email Template for Lead in this case.

Comment: Do you mean it is possible to have a lightning email template using SML for merge fields? If so how, because if I try to save a Lightning template I get error like - "This template doesn’t support SML merge fields. Use the merge field picker to replace merge fields starting with "{!".: HTML Value"

Comment: Of course, SML is still supported in Lightning Email Templates with some minor limitations as [documented](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.merge_fields_email_templates_lex.htm&type=5).